# Why is my function returning an empty string?

Tags: c++, string

I was wondering if someone could please illuminate me on why the below code does not behave the way I expect. By that I mean I expect the line

```
std::cout << myEngine.getDesc() << std::endl;
```

to print out: *"Desc1"*

But I get an empty string? I figured that maybe it was because I was splitting up my rudimentary code into different files incorrectly but I get the same thing when I put all the code into one file.

StringErrorTest.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Engine.h"


int main()
{
    std::cout << "Compiling & Running!";
    Engine myEngine;
    std::string t1 = "Hello ";
    std::cout << myEngine.getDesc() << std::endl;
    std::cout << t1 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Engine.h

```
#include <string>

class Engine {
private:
    std::string m_Description;
    std::string m_Description2;

public:
    Engine();
    std::string getDesc();
    void setDesc(std::string desc);
    std::string getDesc2();
    void setDesc2(std::string desc2);
    std::string spitItOut();

};
```

Engine.cpp

```
#include "Engine.h"

Engine::Engine()
{
    std::string m_Description = "Desc1";
    std::string m_Description2 = "Desc2";
}

std::string Engine::getDesc()
{
    return m_Description;
}

std::string Engine::getDesc2()
{
    return m_Description2;
}
```

By the way I did search for similar questions but they were all a bit more complex than mine. I feel I have a very basic misunderstanding going on here.

Comment: In your constructor you define **local** variable `m_Description`. Change `std::string m_Description = "Desc1";` to `m_Description = "Desc1";` (i.e. remove `std::string` part).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `Engine::Engine()`, you're creating two local objects named `m_Description` and `m_Description2`, which have nothing to do with the data members with same names; they *hide* the names of data members.

What you want to is to *assign* them as

```
Engine::Engine()
{
    m_Description = "Desc1";  // or this->m_Description = "Desc1"
    m_Description2 = "Desc2"; // or this->m_Description2 = "Desc2"
}
```

Or *initialize* them as

```
Engine::Engine() : m_Description("Desc1"), m_Description2("Desc2")
{
}
```

Comment: I understand now.. thank you so much. I'm sorry for such a silly question.

Comment: @yoonsi Since this answers your question, you can accept the answer.